# Android : Set center position item of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I want to implement a view picker which is like a number view picker but instead of picking numbers, it will pick the view in the center of the picker.
[image: Custom number picker]

The basic idea is to get the position of centered item and replace the view at that position with a different view. To do so, I have done following -

I have the following layout -

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">


<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:background="#ffeb3b"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvItems"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

The activity for populating view is -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView rvItems;
    private View view;
    private List<Data> array = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (int i=0; i< 100; i++) {
            final Data data = new Data();
            data.isVisible = true;
            data.data = String.valueOf(i);
            array.add(data);
        }

        view = (View) findViewById(R.id.view);
        rvItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvItems);
        rvItems.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(array));
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvItems.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        rvItems.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int firstVisibleChildPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                int lastVisibleChildPosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                int centerChildPosition = (firstVisibleChildPosition + lastVisibleChildPosition) / 2;

                for (int i=0; i < centerChildPosition; i++) {
                    final Data data = new Data();
                    data.isVisible = false;

                    // Adding empty list at begining and end of position
                    array.add(0, data);
                    array.add(array.size(), data);
                }

                rvItems.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        rvItems.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            int centerChildPosition = -1;

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    int firstVisibleChildPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                    int lastVisibleChildPosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                    centerChildPosition = (firstVisibleChildPosition + lastVisibleChildPosition) / 2;

                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(centerChildPosition);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "center position = " + centerChildPosition );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Using the above code, I am able to know the centered child position but not able to fit it properly inside the yellow rectangle view -

[image: My implementation so far]

How can I make sure that the numbers are within yellow bar? For now, I have added empty views on the top and bottom of the list so that the first and last items in the list can be centered. What is an optimum way to do it?

Comment: Hello, Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I did, I think I have a sample project somewhere, will try to upload it today.

Comment: Okay, let me know once you upload please.

Comment: Did you find the solution?